# Can various users access the same table in database and have different values for everyone?

Tags: php, mysql, apache

Okay, I didn't know how to put this in a sentence. I'm planning to build a web application that lets the users have a track of what books they have read. These books are in a table in MySQL database, along with a boolean column 'is_complete' that is set false by default. When the user clicks 'completed', the value will be set to true in the column.

My question is: Is this possible with a single table of books with the boolean column? Or do I have to create a table for each user with the boolean column and with foreign key(root.books)? What is the best way to get this done? I'm still learning.

P.S. I'm using Apache server, PHP and MySQL

Comment: You'll want not only a `books` table, and a `users` table, but also a `users_books` table that has keys to both of the previous tables. The `users_books` table has your boolean `is_complete` column.

Comment: Thank you, @JonathanM! So it works if I have all these tables in root, right?

Comment: You need to realize that you have a Many-to-Many relationship between books and users, which means that you cannot use a single book table by itself to hold information about what users have done to the books. Instead, as @JonathanM mentioned, you need to represent the M:M relation in your database and make sure that the `is_complete` attribute is part of the row with a `user_id` + `book_id` PK in the associative table.

Comment: Where you place the tables is a different discussion. If you have questions about that, please ask another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some quickly put together example sql of how you might structure a database for this purpose - trying to normalise as far as possible ( we could take normalisation a stage further but that would require another table and probably not worth it for the example )

You could run this in your gui so long as you don't already have a database called `bookworms` just to observe the structure for yourself.

```
drop database if exists `bookworms`;
create database if not exists `bookworms`;
use `bookworms`;


drop table if exists `publishers`;
create table if not exists `publishers` (
  `pid` smallint(5) unsigned not null auto_increment,
  `publisher` varchar(50) not null,
  primary key (`pid`)
) engine=innodb default charset=utf8;


drop table if exists `books`;
create table if not exists `books` (
  `bid` int(10) unsigned not null auto_increment,
  `pid` smallint(5) unsigned not null default 1,
  `title` varchar(50) not null default '0',
  primary key (`bid`),
  key `pid` (`pid`),
  constraint `fk_pid` foreign key (`pid`) references `publishers` (`pid`) on delete cascade on update cascade
) engine=innodb default charset=utf8;


drop table if exists `users`;
create table if not exists `users` (
  `uid` int(10) unsigned not null auto_increment,
  `username` varchar(50) not null default '0',
  primary key (`uid`)
) engine=innodb default charset=utf8;


drop table if exists `library`;
create table if not exists `library` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned not null auto_increment,
  `uid` int(10) unsigned not null default '0',
  `bid` int(10) unsigned not null default '0',
  `status` tinyint(3) unsigned not null default '0' comment 'indicates if the book has been read',
  primary key (`id`),
  key `uid` (`uid`),
  key `bid` (`bid`),
  constraint `fk_bid` foreign key (`bid`) references `books` (`bid`) on delete cascade on update cascade,
  constraint `fk_uid` foreign key (`uid`) references `users` (`uid`) on delete cascade on update cascade
) engine=innodb default charset=utf8;




insert into `publishers` (`pid`, `publisher`) values
    (1, 'unknown'),
    (2, 'penguin'),
    (3, 'faber cassell'),
    (4, 'domino'),
    (5, 'unknown');

insert into `books` (`bid`, `pid`, `title`) values
    (1, 1, 'miss piggy got caught shoplifting'),
    (2, 2, 'my life on crack by kermit the frog');

insert into `users` (`uid`, `username`) values
    (1, 'joe bloggs'),
    (2, 'fred smith'),
    (3, 'john doe');

insert into `library` (`id`, `uid`, `bid`, `status`) values
    (1, 1, 1, 1),
    (2, 2, 2, 1);
```

Then, when you need to query for a particular book, user or publisher a derivation of the following:

```
$sql="select * from library l
    left outer join users u on u.uid=l.uid
    left outer join books b on b.bid=l.bid
    left outer join publishers p on p.pid=b.pid
    where u.username='joe bloggs';";
```

Comment: Thank you so much @RamRaider! That clarifies everything.

Answer (score 0):

you need books table and users table and table books_users with id's of book and id of user who clicked is_completed (and with that you don't need boolean is_completed)

Answer (score 0):

**Impossible.** The database looks the same for any user.
You don't have to create a table for each user either! That would be a really stupid solution.
Just create a table with two columns: user ID and book ID with proper links/joins/etc. If the user have already read the book, add a row inside this table with the corresponding user and book IDs. To check if the user have already read the book, just look for a row in this new table with the corresponding user and book IDs. If such a row is in the table - the user have already completed the book. If not - he had not.
As the row can't create itself, the default value is that he have not read the book yet. By removing the row you may also "change the user's history" - that will mark the book as incompleted by that user.

Answer (score -2):

Yes this is possible. Set it up so when each user registers each book is set to false as you were stating. 
Here is an example: 
[image: https://i.gyazo.com/4e65fffdcadf2b2df648ef7abef5155d.png]

As each user is added, the book_id column is set to false for that user.

As others stated, of course you will need the Users table, but if you wanted, you could just transfer the user_id and setup a table like pictured above with each book (book_id into multiple columns) set to false. It would be easier to manager and understand.

Comment: Usually `false` is not a good id value. You typically will not want to create a record for each book when a user registers. Only create records when the user indicates they're reading the book.

Comment: That was not the question. They asked for a single table of books.

Comment: @BlakeConnally If there a single table of books and nothing else, then the system would work for only a single user. With a M:M relation, you need an associative table.

Comment: @Blake Yeah, that won't work well. His actual question was `What is the best way to get this done?`

Comment: @BlakeConnally I removed your Skype information from the post. This is not the place for that stuff. Use the comments and/or discussion area for chatting instead.

Comment: Neither a user_id nor a book_id are likely to be VARCHAR. They are both however likely to be PRIMARY.  I don't understand your final sentence.